# inserting into sqlite database creates extra fields using PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

Hi I'm inserting data using PHP into a SQLite database. I would like to name the fields (i.e., ID, authors etc.) but when the data gets inserted I get extra data where [0] = [ID] and [1] = [authors]

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO citation (ID,authors, etc.) 
            VALUES ('$ID','$AF', etc.)";
$db->exec($sql);
```

gives this when printed:

```
[0] => 0
[ID] => 0
[1] => Li, Shun-Li;Xu, Qiang
[authors] => Li, Shun-Li;Xu, Qiang
```

Is this problem inherent in SQLite databases and I should just live with it? Or am I inserting it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation on [`SQLite3Result::fetchArray()`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php).

> Fetches a result row as an associative or numerically indexed array or both. By default, fetches as both.

So instead of

```
SQLite3Result::fetchArray()
```

use

```
SQLite3Result::fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)
```